# setInterval using the value before last?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, message, local-storage, setinterval

I'm developing a Google Chrome extension and I'm having a rather.. odd problem. (I'll try and keep this as simple as I can)

Basically, I allow the user to customise the interval speed of a `setInterval` loop.
I do this with an input box which, when data is entered, sets a `localStorage` value on `keyUp`. The `localStorage` value is then passed to the content script via Chrome's message passing API and the `setInterval` loop automatically picks it up.

**options.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" id="customTime_Input" onKeyUp="setPref_customTime()" />

        <!--Call JavaScript functions after all elements are created-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="messagePassing.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="options.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**background.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="messagePassing.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="content.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

**messagePassing.js**

```js
if(localStorage["scanTime"] == undefined || localStorage["scanTime"] == ""){
   localStorage["scanTime"] = 2000;
}

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.method == "getScanTime"){
            sendResponse({data: localStorage["scanTime"]});
            console.log("scanTime LS, response: " + localStorage["scanTime"]);
        }
    }
);
```

**options.js**

```js
function setPref_customTime(){
   var inputBoxElement = document.getElementById("customTime_Input");

   localStorage["scanTime"] = inputBoxElement.value;
   console.log("scanTime LS, setPref_customTime(): " + localStorage["scanTime"]);
}
```

**content.js**

```js
window.load = passMessages();
function passMessages(){
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "getScanTime"}, function(response) {
        localStorage["scanTime"] = response.data;
        console.log("scanTime LS, request: " + localStorage["scanTime"]);
    });

    scanPage();
}

function scanPage(){
    console.log("scanTime LS, scanPage: " + localStorage["scanTime"]);

    setInterval(function match(){
        console.log("scanTime LS, match: " + localStorage["scanTime"]);
    }, localStorage["scanTime"]);
}
```

And the console returns these logs after a custom value is entered (it returns "2000" for all logs when default value is loaded, like it should):

```
scanTime LS, scanPage: 2000
scanTime LS, scanPage: 2000
scanTime LS, request: 5000
scanTime LS, request: 5000
scanTime LS, scanPage: 2000
scanTime LS, request: 5000
scanTime LS, match: 5000
scanTime LS, match: 5000
scanTime LS, match: 5000
scanTime LS, match: 5000
[etc]
```

It clearly shows that `setInterval` is using the new value, yet the page and log refreshes at the speed of the old value (and it's no user-error. I've used vastly different values multiple times and had the same results). How can a `localStorage` with the same name have different values a few lines apart?

**Update**: I've just noticed that the console reports all `console.log()` commands except for "scanTime LS, response: ". Is this significant?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are seeing is you have one loop running with 2000 ms and then just start a new  loop with 5000 ms leaving you with two loops running at once. You need to cancel the first one when you start the second one using [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval).

Something like this should work.

```
function scanPage(){
    console.log("scanTime LS, scanPage: " + localStorage["scanTime"]);

    if (localStorage["intervalID"]) {
      clearInterval(localStorage["intervalID"]);
    }

    localStorage["intervalID"] = setInterval(function match(){
        console.log("scanTime LS, match: " + localStorage["scanTime"]);
    }, localStorage["scanTime"]);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was odd that multiple logs were being reported. I'll try that now and get back to you. :)

Comment: Nope. Plugged in your code and it's still having the exact same effect. :/

Comment: You might have to convert the intervalID back to an int.

Comment: I don't understand.. Could you explain a little more clearly or edit your code, please?

Comment: setInterval returns an integer `5`, `localStorage["intervalID"]` returns a string `"5"`. `clearInterval` may only work wit integers. `clearInterval(parseInt(localStorage["intervalID"]));`